# A button to copy your email address to clipboard in Mac OS

Tags: mac, script

My e-mail address is long and every time i get asked to insert it somewhere, i spend time writing it and reading it twice before i submit it and still sometimes i send the wrong e-mail address.
It would be extremely handy to have a button in the application bar, that copies my e-mail to the clipboard so that i can just click on that button and paste it in the fields i need, in spite of writing it manually.
I am using Mac OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AppleScript**

You can write a short AppleScript

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the clipboard to "mylongemail@example.com"
end tell
```

Open the *AppleScript Editor*, paste the example and save it as an application. You can then put it in your dock to access it quickly.

**Terminal**

You can use `pbcopy` to copy text to the clipboard

```
echo 'mylongemail@example.com' | pbcopy
```

You can either define an alias

```
alias ce="echo 'mylongemail@example.com' | pbcopy"
```

or put it in a file as a shell script

Answer (score 3):

I use the text expansion feature built into Mac OS X to automatically put in email address using a short abbreviations.

This will work in standard text fields in Cocoa apps, like TextEdit, Mail etc; alternatively (paid) software like TextExpander (by Smile Software) works in apps like Sublime Text. 
Information here:
http://lifehacker.com/5931337/do-yourself-a-favor-set-up-mountain-lions-built-in-text-expansion-with-these-shortcuts

Or you could probably write an Applescript/Automator Service to do this and assign a keyboard shortcut or select it from the menubar.

Comment: cool thanks but it doesn't work on everything: for example it doesn't work with Sublime Text.